# NodeJS | filter Device depending on "Source" name for ARP protocoll and Broadcast destination

Tags: node.js, wireshark, broadcast, arp

I have an Ubiquiti Access Point in my network and via wireshark i can see that it sends a broadcast via ARP (as you can see in the image below):

- as source it always has the prefix "Ubiquiti_"
- Destination: Broadcast
- Protocol: ARP

### [Wireshark Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oEyr.png)

Now I wanted to filter for this fixed Prefix "Ubiquiti_" to get the devices MAC and IP adress dynamically (without knowing them beforehand). I have searched for broadcast / arp node js packages but most of them are programmed in a way, where you need to know the IP of the device you want to listen to - and in this case I would like to do that dynamically.

If I could somehow get the same result via a nodejs package / code that I get currently via Wireshark at the moment, it would solve my problem.

Any tips or hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions by now. If anyone has a similar problem, please try these:

- the npm package "local-devices" accesses the ARP table and returns all the IPs and MAC adresses. That combined with an vendor oui (Organizationally unique identifier) database allows to filter for the ubiquiti device.
- with the dgram dependency i start a server that listens on a configured port. in my case i needed to listen on port 10001 for the message that gets send by the ubiquiti. With dgrams on('message', ..) i can get the message aswell as the IP adress of the ubiquiti and work with that